# Problem to show more than one texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, android, glsl

I'm trying to build a dodecahedron dice. The problem I face is that I'm not able to show more than one texture. I have 12 textures, one for each face.

I guess the problem is on the fragment shader, because I'm able to load all the textures, but I don't know how to assign them to the gl_FragColor.

```
"precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit0;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit1;" +
        "uniform vec4 a_Color;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates0;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates1;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit0, v_TextureCoordinates0);" +
        "  vec4 textureColor2 = texture2D(u_TextureUnit1, v_TextureCoordinates1);" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(a_Color.rgb, textureColor2.rgb, textureColor2.a), 1.0);" +
        "}"
```

For now, I tried to show only 2 different textures, as soon as I find the way to show them I will do the same for the ones that are missing.

I tried to create a new texture from the other two:

```
"  vec4 mixTex = texture2D(textureColor + textureColor2);"+
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(a_Color.rgb, mixTex.rgb, mixTex.a), 1.0);" +
```

and make a mix:

```
"  vec4 mixTex = vec4(mix(textureColor.rgb,textureColor2.rgb,textureColor2.a), 1.0);"+
        "  gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(a_Color.rgb, mixTex.rgb, mixTex.a), 1.0);" +
```

The furthest I've come has been to show two different textures overlapped on all faces.
[image]

Comment: A typical solution here would be to compose all 12 face textures into one "atlas" texture and render the mesh with that atlas. Or, alternatively (and less efficiently), to split each face into a separate mesh and bind a different texture when rendering each one. You could also stack the 12 faces into an array texture, and use a 3D texture coordinate to look up the appropriate layer to sample for each face, which behaves similarly to atlassing.

Comment: Wow, DMGregory, thanks a lot!. I searched some information about atlas and now I'm able to texture all faces correctly!

Comment: Excellent! Want to write up your solution as an Answer below to help the next person struggling with a similar issue?